# Matching second data source entries to primary source

Tags: python, python-3.x

First post here.

I have a large dataset (80gb .tsv) sliced by state (1gb> - 12gb individually) like the table below. Roughly 62mil rows.

```
+--------+----+----+----+
| county | c1 | c2 | c3 |
+--------+----+----+----+
| A      | 1  | 2  | 3  |
+--------+----+----+----+
| B      | 2  | 1  | 3  |
+--------+----+----+----+
| C      | 4  | 1  | 2  |
+--------+----+----+----+
```

and another much simple .csv table, with 83 counties

```
+--------+------------+
| county | population |
+--------+------------+
| a      | 1          |
+--------+------------+
| b      | 2          |
+--------+------------+
| c      | 4          |
+--------+------------+
```

how would join/match the two files to add the population to the top table to look like

```
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
| county | c1 | c2 | c3 | population |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
| A      | 1  | 2  | 3  | 1          |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
| B      | 2  | 2  | 3  | 2          |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
| C      | 4  | 1  | 2  | 4          |
+--------+----+----+----+------------+
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It is important that your question be clear and unambiguous. You have the county names capitalized in your tsv file but lower-case in your csv table. If they are normalized to all upper-case, will the county names still be distinct? Is it guaranteed that the county names are distinct in the csv table? What exactly is to be the output--a new tsv file, or the old file to be updated, or something else? Do you want only basic Python code or can a library be used? Finally, what work have you done on this problem and where are you stuck?

Comment: File 1 .tsv: Column name BUYER_COUNTY is what I need to match to the second file. File 2 .csv: column names County & Population. I'd like to match BUYER_COUNTY to County and add Population to the df/initial file and save/export as .csv. Moving from Tableau/viz to a more comprehensive role, so apologies for the ambiguity, & thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to read the first file and group its lines by their primary keys (in your case, that would be "county"). I'm not completely sure, how your data is structured, so you might adapt the filename and the delimiter.

```
import csv
reader = csv.DictReader(open("file1.csv"), delimiter=";")
d = {row["county"]: row for row in reader}
```

Then you have to read the second file and update the existing rows.

```
reader = csv.DictReader(open("file2.csv"), delimiter=";")
for row in reader:
    d[row["county"]].update(row)
```

Now you have a dictionary, that contains the merged row for every primary key. Since i assume you want to store this result in a file, you have to iterate over every value in the dictionary and write them to a file with `writerows`.

```
headers = list(d[row["county"]])
writer = csv.DictWriter(open("output.csv", "w"), fieldnames=headers, delimiter=";", lineterminator="\n")
writer.writeheader()
writer.writerows(d.values())
```

Comment: import csv  
reader = csv.DictReader(open("data/arcos-mi-statewide-itemized.tsv"), delimiter=";")  
d = {row['BUYER_COUNTY']: row for row in reader}  
reader = csv.DictReader(open("data/mipop.csv"), delimiter=";")  
for row in reader:  
    d[row["County"]].update(row)  

headers = list(d[row["County"]])  
writer = csv.DictWriter(open("output.csv", "w"), fieldnames=headers, delimiter=";",  
 lineterminator="\n")  
writer.writeheader()  
writer.writerows(d.values())  

Error
    KeyError: 'BUYER_COUNTY'

Comment: @electiondaze Do you use semi-colons as delimiters, otherwise you have to adapt the delimiter parameter in the csv.DictReader constructor